# Converting pairwise to list with varying number of rows based on value

Tags: python, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a set of pairwise origin and destination data as rows. Each of these has a count of persons moving from the origin to the destination. This count of people is varies considerably (from ~4 persons to >200).

What I'm trying to achieve is a conversion of these rows into a list wise where two rows represent a move.... this sounds counter intuitive, but it's the format I need to read the data into a mapping package I'm using.

I'm hoping the image below better illustrates what I'm trying to do - the red cells represent 4 moves (the Total column) this is then converted into 8 rows with the origin and destination paring repeated 4 times.

Excel will work in the interim (as a proof of concept), although if I'm going to crunch the entire data set, I'll get over a two million records (at least) - so a database or Python solution would be needed - just to generate a *.csv file of the final list.

**Note** - the Total column *doubled* indicates the numbers of rows needed - so if 5 people move, it will need 10 rows.

[image: Schematic Change]

So - I've flagged this question for Excel, Access or Python solutions. I'm a novice in either VBA or Python, but am open for suggestions.

**Update**
Thanks heaps Salo! The solution worked great (with appropriate altering of file paths for the input and output .csv) - here's a screen shot of the animation drawn from the data!

[image]

Comment: You can generate the csv file directly - it's not like the output needs to fit in Excel...  What format is the original data in?

Comment: While your visualization is nice, it would help if you also put a snippet of some raw input data (we don't know if it is excel or csv or whatsoever) and also post what you have tried so far. With Python it is easy to go through the file line by line and then generate the new entries with a loop based on your 'Total' column. If you need a csv in the end anyway and you haven't started, try it with python :)

Comment: Tim - its a CSV, I just used Excel for picture. Output as CSV is what's required

Comment: @AndrewTice thanks for showing the result, looks nice :) Glad that i could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that your input looks like this:

```
origx, origy, destx, desty, Total
0.0, 0.0, 1.1, 1.1, 2
151.1556, -33.9113, 150.9991, -33.7297, 4
```

for converting it into this:

```
ID, X, Y, Column pair
1, 0.0, 0.0, origx|origy
1, 1.1, 1.1, destx|desty
2, 0.0, 0.0, origx|origy
2, 1.1, 1.1, destx|desty
3, 151.1556, -33.9113, origx|origy
3, 150.9991, -33.7297, destx|desty
4, 151.1556, -33.9113, origx|origy
4, 150.9991, -33.7297, destx|desty
5, 151.1556, -33.9113, origx|origy
5, 150.9991, -33.7297, destx|desty
6, 151.1556, -33.9113, origx|origy
6, 150.9991, -33.7297, destx|desty
```

#### Python code

```
def write_header(f):
    f.write('ID, X, Y, Column pair\n')

def skip_header(f):
    f.next()

def main():
    my_id = 1
    with open('input.csv', 'r') as in_f:
        skip_header(in_f)
        with open('output.csv', 'w') as out_f:
            write_header(out_f)
            for line in in_f:
                orig_x, orig_y, dest_x, dest_y, total = \
                    [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]
                for idx in range(int(total)):
                    out_f.write(
                        '{}, {}, {}, origx|origy\n'.format(my_id, orig_x, orig_y))
                    out_f.write(
                        '{}, {}, {}, destx|desty\n'.format(my_id, dest_x, dest_y))
                    my_id += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I didn't write many comments in the code, so please ask for more clarification if you need it :)

Comment: thanks for this. Will give it a go when back in the office tomorrow (it's evening in Australia ;))

Comment: ...although also to say that the code looks initiative and you assumed the data structure correctly!